# Does Linux Mint have same advertisement "features" like Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, advertisements

Does Linux Mint have same advertisement "features" like Ubuntu? I'm an absolute beginner using a Desktop Linux (used Debian for years on a server) and want to know whether I'm "safe for ads" installing Linux Mint instead of Ubuntu.

Comment: Correct, it does not have the Amazon suggestions nor the suggested apps.

Answer (score 1):

No. http://www.linuxmint.com/searchengines.php

But like in ubuntu, you can disable it :

[image]